quote? Телеграмм код смотрит каналы по ключ словам, но как только в сообщение появляется формат Quote, то он его не видит, а точнее видит но unknown
quote? Телеграмм код смотрит каналы по ключ словам, но как только в сообщение появляется формат Quote, то он его не видит, а точнее видит но пишет unknown
использую pyrogram
код дать не смогу, но если хотите помочь, то скажите как сделать так чтобы сообщения с форматом quote были видны, пишу на python

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

"код дать не смогу" => а мы не можем сказать "как сделать", читайте документацию
